# Observable value doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get notification token value from fcm service to my component, but token observable doesn't update after i fetch token from plugin.

This is my fcm.service.ts
I fetch the token in my app component.

```
      private notificationToken = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
      sharedNotificationToken$ = this.notificationToken.asObservable();
  
      // This is called in the app component
      PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
        (token: Token) => {
          console.log('token: ', token) // here token has value
          this.notificationToken.next(token.value);
        }
      );
```

And when I try to get token value from another component, it returns null (initial observable value).

```
        ngOnInit(){
          this.fcmService.sharedNotificationToken$.subscribe(token => {
          // here token is NULL
          this.notificationToken = token;
       })
     }
```

Comment: You're logging `token` but emitting `token.value` is that correct ? If you log `token.value` does it contain any value ?

Comment: Yes, it's string value I want to get.

Comment: Maybe you have two different instances of your service.  Are you using `providedIn: root`  for your `fcmService`?

Comment: have you looked into using [`emittery`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emittery)?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get null is because you set your `BehaviorSubject` to null by doing this:

```ts
   private notificationToken = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
```

**Behavior Subject**: New subscribers get the last published value OR initial value immediately upon subscription.

**Subject**: A subscriber will only get published values thereon-after the subscription is made.

**Replay Subject**: New subscribers get all previously published value(s) immediately upon subscription.

**Async Subject** - Emits latest value to observers upon completion.

Here is the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) for subjects.

> In the following example, the BehaviorSubject is initialized with the value 0 which the first Observer receives when it subscribes. The second Observer receives the value 2 even though it subscribed after the value 2 was sent.

```ts
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

// New behavior subject initialized with 0 as default value
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(0);
 
// Subscribes to the subject to log observerA
subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerA: ${v}`)
});
 
// set subject value to 1
subject.next(1);

// set subject value to 2
subject.next(2);
 
// subscribe to subject and log observerB
subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerB: ${v}`)
});
 
// set subject value to 3
subject.next(3);
 
// Output Console Logs
// observerA: 0
// observerA: 1
// observerA: 2
// observerB: 2
// observerA: 3
// observerB: 3
```

Further more on the topic of instances of your service:

If you add a service only to `@NgModule({ providers: [YourService] })` and no where else, then there will always be one instance of `YourService` in the whole application.

However this is only true when the `@NgModule()` decorator is on a non lazy loaded module. The `Providers` of lazy loaded modules can be imported with a `forRoot` to ensure the service will be a singleton.

If you add services to `@Component({ providers: [...] })` then you will have as many instances as there are instances of the component.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know what the difference was between all of these, so I just always used subject and used different methods of emitting previous data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem was that I was adding service to `@Component({ providers: [...] })`. It worked after I removed it from component providers.